# C++ How to the total number of duplicate elements in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am trying to finish my homework, but I have encountered some problems in the item of Duplicate Elements. I have tried to find out where the problem is, but I cannot find it. My code works fine when the sequence is small, but it becomes problematic when the sequence is large.[image]

In this sequence, I expect to get the number in the picture, but I always get the number in the second picture. As you can see, there is always a problem in this item in the duplicate element.[image]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int arrayA[25];
    int arrayB[25];
    int min,max;
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    //Input
    cout << "Input the number of elements to store in the array: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << n << endl;
    cout << "Input "<< n <<" integers:" << endl;
    //Store arrayA
    if(count < n){
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cin >> num;
            cout << "integer - " << count;
            cout << " : " << num <<endl;
            arrayA[count] = num;
            count++;
        }
    }
    //store arrayB
    for(i = 0;i < count; i++){
        arrayB[i] = arrayA[count - i - 1];
    }

    //Forwards Array
    cout << "The values stored into the array are :" << endl;
    for(i = 0;i < count; i++){
        cout << arrayA[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Backwards Array
    cout << "The values stored into the array in reverse are :" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        cout << arrayB[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Sum
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        sum += arrayA[i];
    }

    //Max & Min
    for(i = 0; i < count;i++){
        if(max < arrayA[i]){
            max = arrayA[i];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(min > arrayA[i]){
            min = arrayA[i];
        }
        if(arrayA[i]== 0){
            min = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Duplicate elements
    count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(temp = i + 1; temp < n; temp++){
            if(arrayA[i] == arrayA[temp] ){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "The sum of all elements of the array is ";
    cout << " " << sum << endl;
    cout << "The total number of duplicate elements in the array is ";
    cout << count << endl;
    cout << "The maximum and minimum element in the array are ";
    cout << min << " , " << max;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You output should have been included as text, not images. Have you considered what happens if a number occurs more that twice (like "4" does in your example)?

Comment: Just by printing what items you are comparing when you are counting, a simple debug step, would give you a lot of insight.

Answer (score -1):

You should try debugging more by printing, to know what is happening. You are not really taking into account that a number can be repeated several times and depending on the spread, it will count them several times. And here is why:

```
//Duplicate elements
count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(temp = i + 1; temp < n; temp++){
        //cout << "Comparing "<<  arrayA[i] << " to "<< arrayA[temp]<<endl; 
        if(arrayA[i] == arrayA[temp] ){
            cout << "ITEM DUPLICATED at i , "<<i<< " item "<< arrayA[i]<< " and temp "<< temp<< " item "<< arrayA[temp] << endl;
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> ITEM DUPLICATED at i , 0 item 4 and temp 7 item 4
> ITEM DUPLICATED at i , 2 item -2 and temp 10 item -2
> ITEM DUPLICATED at i , 4 item -3 and temp 14 item -3
> ITEM DUPLICATED at i , 5 item 3 and temp 11 item 3
> ITEM DUPLICATED at i , 7 item 4 and temp 8 item 4
> ITEM DUPLICATED at i , 12 item -1 and temp 13 item -1

As you can see, there is a 4 - 4 twice. It can be seen quite easily if you do it in paper (although you shouldn't)

> 4A -4B -2C 1D -3E 3F 5G 4H 4I 0J -2K 3L -1M -1N -3O

> 4a -4b -2c   1d   -3e 3f 5g 4h 4i 0j -2k 3l -1m -1n -3o

Connections made:

4A 4h

-2C -2k

-3E -3o

3F 3l

4H 4i

So the code technically is doing what you are asking it to do. if you want to count UNIQUELY (if a 4 appears 15 times, count it as only that 4 is repeated), you should be checking if the number has already been checked. Using a vector or map (dictionaries in C++) can allow you to do that! Or lists with lists (the element, and the number of occurences)